# The process dwm.exe is maxing the CPU after user login

Tags: windows, dwm, windows-10-v1903

Since the May Update (v1903), the process dwm.exe is causing me trouble in the form that it maxes out cpu (one core) after a user logs in and this does not go away by itself either.

Strangely enough, killing the dwm.exe process in question does not affect the session of the user that logged on at that time at all. (while just blindly killing all dwm.exe processes would).

This is a multi core system, however as more users log in, it does this for every user and since this can max out the cpu over the entire night/weekend etc. if not stopped, it is certainly a problem.

I have done a lot of reading on dwm.exe on the internet and have also checked that the graphic card driver is up to date.

I have not really found any cases online that seem to be the same as this one here.

I understand that the DWM is an essential part of Windows for some years now and that it therefore cannot simply be disabled.

As I am completely at a loss here, this would now go in the direction of putting on a silly band-aid like a script that kills the specific dwm.exe process every time one hugs the cpu but not sure if it would be a reliable solution.

This is in no way an exotic configuration and there are also no "rare" programs in use here.

If anyone has experienced this and could enlighten me on the cause of this, that would be much appreciated.